# "Unable to cast transparent proxy to type" when using AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap method

Tags: c#, appdomain

I'm getting this error when trying to get instanse of class in separated Application Domain. Here is code:

```
string assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
string typeName = "Namespace.ClassName";

AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
SecurityZone zone = SecurityZone.MyComputer;

// Set up the Evidence
Evidence baseEvidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
Evidence evidence = new Evidence(baseEvidence);
evidence.AddAssembly(assemblyName);
evidence.AddHost(new Zone(zone));

AppDomain app = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Processor AppDomain", evidence, setup);
core = (Core)app.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName);
```

Both classes (calling and called) are **in same assemby** (COM dll).

So does anybody know what is the reason ot this exception? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Are you sure `typeName` refers to the `Core` type? What does the debugger show when you look at the result of `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()` without casting?

Comment: Thanks for response, svick. `typeName` realy refers to `Core`, otherwise I'll get other exception of type `FileNotFoundException` or `TypeLoadException`. When I changed last string of this example to `Object core = app.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assemblyName, typeName);` and debugged it, everything was going right scenario - fields of Core class was initialized, constructor called and object was returned. But this returned object is `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy` by type for calling class. and looks like I could not cast this object to `Core` type.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to achieve. The purpose of creating an object in a separate AppDomain is to isolate parts of your application. By casting to the implementation that resides in the second AppDomain, you're trying to break the marshalling and the isolation, aren't you ?

Comment: Nice assumption Seb, but there are some conditions to think that AppDomain should provide a convenient methods for working with related Objects, and `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap` method is on of them. You can see that I'm trying to do the same thing as posted on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx (see an Example).

Comment: Is your type you are trying to create in new app domain marked with `Serializable` or does your type inherit `MarshalByRefObject` type?

Comment: Yes of course... class `Core` is inherited from class that is inherited from `MarshalByRefObject`. Otherwise first of all there will be "Type '...Core' in assembly '..., Version=...., Culture=neutral **is not marked as serializable.**"} exception! Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your application referencing the com dll? Is this also a .net dll? If it is being referenced as a project by your application and is also registered as a com dll, then there is a chance that your app is refering to two different copies of the dll in which case it will consider your Core classes to be two separate classes as they are in different dlls. You could consider hooking up the appdomains AssemblyLoad event to debug this and check the location of the assembly being loaded.

Comment: My assembly is a .Net COM dll, which is used from c++ project. As i said, both classes (calling and called) are in same assembly. In this case i don't understand why there will be another assembly. When i debugging both classes (calling and called) and doing `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, it returned same result for both classes. I hope i understand right your idea...

Comment: Why don't you try using AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap which will allow you to specify the path to the dll.